# Launching a .class file with java with a script

Tags: java, nautilus

I'm trying to use a nautilus script in Ubuntu 11.04 to launch the currently selected file in java.  So i'm trying to do java FileName in a script.  Currently I have

```
!/bin/bash
test = 'java' + $@
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e test
```

My question is why this doesn't work.  I've been able to get it to work if I pass a string of the full file name, like

```
!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e '!/etc/etc/etc/test.class'
```

But that doesn't let me open the current file, so how can I pass the currently selected file into it, I also tried 'java' + test to, that didn't work either.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The `$` tells it `$test` is a variable, but `$` is only used after the variable is assigned, so the second line is unchanged.

```
!/bin/bash
test = 'java ${@}'
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e $test
```

Comment: I was unable to get that to work, but I was able to get it to work by using    #!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --execute java `basename $1 .class'

Comment: You also then need a space after `java` in the shell script, then. See my answer now.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, but that code in my comment appears to do the job fine, thanks for the help though!